# Touching a file on each mount point declared in `ansible_mounts`

Tags: ansible

I want to get info about mount points so that I can touch a file on them.

I can get mount points through `item.mount` but I want to store those mount points inside a variable so I can use it to form a path like `{{mountpoint}}/test.txt`.

But I don't know how to store that info to variable from the result of my debug task. And even if I get those mount points, I don't know how to create a file inside each mount point directories.

Should I use a loop again for that?

This is the playbook I have so far:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - setup:
        filter: ansible_mounts
    - debug:
        var: item.mount
      loop: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
      register: result
```

Which gives

```
TASK [setup] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [ambertest]
 
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [ambertest] => (item={u'block_used': 258025, u'uuid': u'55555-c55c-55-555-0555a', u'size_total': 55584, u'block_total': 13104379, u'mount': u'/', u'block_available': 12846354, u'size_available': 5554, u'fstype': u'xfs', u'inode_total': 25524, u'inode_available': 558, u'device': u'/dev/vda1', u'inode_used': 30796, u'block_size': 4096, u'options': u'rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota'}) => {
"item": {
"block_available": 5554,
"block_size": 4096,
"block_total": 13559,
"block_used": 2555,
"device": "/dev/vda1",
"fstype": "xfs",
"inode_available": 2558,
"inode_total": 255824,
"inode_used": 355,
"mount": "/",
"options": "rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota",
"size_available": 5554,
"size_total": 5554,
"uuid": "55555"
},
"item.mount": "/"
}
ok: [ambertest] => (item={u'block_used': 672774, u'uuid': u'55dc9f5589e', u'size_total': 55, u'block_total': 155558, u'mount': u'/amber', u'block_available': 554, u'size_available': 49954627584, u'fstype': u'ext4', u'inode_total': 355, u'inode_available': 559, u'device': u'/dev/vdb', u'inode_used': 11, u'block_size': 4096, u'options': u'rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered'}) => {
"item": {
"block_available": 1554,
"block_size": 4556,
"block_total": 558,
"block_used": 6554,
"device": "/dev/vdb",
"fstype": "ext4",
"inode_available": 559,
"inode_total": 550,
"inode_used": 11,
"mount": "/amber",
"options": "rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered",
"size_available": 45584,
"size_total": 55,
"uuid": "5555"
},
"item.mount": "/amber"
}
 
PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************
ambertest : ok=2 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is really far from optimized and bullet proofed but will at least give you an idea of how to start. Basically, you don't need to store your mount points inside a variable since the `ansible_mounts` variable already has them (as brilliantly demonstrated in your question)

```yaml
---
- hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: touch a test.txt file on each existing mountpoint
      file:
        path: "{{ item.mount }}/test.txt"
        state: touch
      loop: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
```

Comment: *nix deals with any number of adjacent slashes as if they are a single one

Comment: A great deal of my roles would not work if that was not the case ;) I always put a slash at the end of dirs just in case and add a slash as separator between two vars always

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Just a dummy proof run: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/259760217d23ae626cd6c43d318a03ae

Comment: [Thanks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/165925) :)

Comment: So, really from what I red further, while it is true for `foo//bar`, [it can be different on some distro for `//foo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256497/on-what-systems-is-foo-bar-different-from-foo-bar).

Comment: Which kind of makes sense when you think about Win implementation that would address network devices via `\\some-network-device\foo`

Comment: The filter [*community.general.path_join*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide.html#paths) solves this problem.

Comment: @AMBER The SO way to say thank you is to accept (green tick) and/or upvote questionS you find useful. Glad I could help.